# How to get address from Google maps(V2) by touching the map in android

Tags: android, google-maps, street-address

i am developing an application, in that i need to display googlemap(V2) and i need to get the address of the particular location when i touch on the map. I did this in previous version of google maps. In the new version i used the following code for dispalying the map, but i dont know how to get the address of the location when i touch on the map.

So, Please guide me how to implement this one.

```
 private GoogleMap map;
 final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(current_latitude, current_longitude);
 map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
 Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG)
        .title("Hamburg"));
       // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
 map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(HAMBURG, 15));
    // Zoom in, animating the camera.
 map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580770/how-can-i-get-address-information-by-touching-screen-on-android-google-map

Comment: http://mirnauman.wordpress.com/2012/04/16/android-google-maps-tutorial-part-6-getting-the-location-that-is-touched/

Comment: in V2 my answer makes the trick!

Answer (score 3):

Just add implemantation of `OnMapClickListener` to your map activity. Like :

```
        public class GoogleMapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements 
        LocationSource,LocationListener,OnMapClickListener,
        OnMapLongClickListener,OnMarkerDragListener,
        OnMarkerClickListener
```

Then :

```
 map.setOnMapClickListener(this);
    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng arg0) {
        //Make Your implementation HERE
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine `OnMapClickListener` as suggested by Sercan Ozdemir with [Geocoder.getFromLocation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocation%28double,%20double,%20int%29).

Remember to use threads (AsyncTask) as `Geocoder` makes a network call to get the actual address.

Alternatively you can use [geocoding API from Google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/), which is a bit more work (network communication, parsing).